# Fetch post api from React Client to express server causes error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I'm trying to send user id and password in React frontend (running on localhost:8080) to express backend server(running on localhost:5000) using post method, but when I click button for submit it says cannot Post /login

Below is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import'whatwg-fetch';

function postSend(url, data) {
  return fetch(url, {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    mode: 'cors', 
    method: 'POST', // 'GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE', etc.
    body: JSON.stringify(data), // Coordinate the body type with 'Content-Type'
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }),
  }).then((res) => res.json())
  .then((result) => console.log(result))
  .catch((error) =>{
    console.error(error, 'postRequest error');
  })
};

class Signup extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { id: "", password: ""}
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const API = 'http://localhost:8080/';
    const DEFAULT_QUERY = 'routes';
    fetch(API + DEFAULT_QUERY, {
  headers : { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
   },
   mode: 'cors'

  }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ data }))
    .catch(function(err) {console.log(err)});
}

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name] : event.target.value });
  };
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    postSend('http://localhost:5000/login', this.state);


  }
    render() { 
        return ( <div>

            <h1>Welcome to Secret Admirer</h1>
            <form action = "/login" method = "POST"  > <hr/>
                <label>Enter Your Credentials to sign up</label>
                <div className ="form-group">
                <p>user id: 
                <input  type="text" value = {this.state.id} onChange={this.handleChange} name="id" placeholder="Enter your ID..."  required />
                </p><br/></div>
                <div className = "form-group">
                <p>Password: 
                <input type="text" value = {this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" required />
                </p><br/></div>
             <button className = "btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Sign up" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> Sign Up</button>
            </form>

            </div>

        )}
}

export default Signup;
```

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const user = require('../db/user');

const router = express.Router();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});


//Sign Up
router.post('/login', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    var newUser = new user.User(req.body);
    newUser.save().then(item => {
        res.redirect('/signin.html');
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send(err,"Unable to save to database");
    });
});


//Sign in logic
router.post('/signin', urlencodedParser, async(req,res) => {
    // check is id exist
    let userid = await user.User.findOne({id: req.body.id});
    if (!userid) {
        res.status(400).send('Invalid id please sign up');
    } else {
        let userpass = await user.User.findOne({
            id: req.body.id,
            password: req.body.password
        });
        if (!userpass) {
            return res.status(400).send('Wrong password');
        }
        res.redirect('/login-success.html');
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I would like POST call to work instead of getting cannot POST /login

Comment: your *server* code doesn't allow CORS

Comment: @JaromandaX how do I make server to allow CORS?

Comment: Use the cors package https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't quite get how this works can you show me the implementation example?

Comment: I think the implementation example given in the package documentation  should be enough - I mean, all I'd do is regurgitate the exact same example `var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
 
app.use(cors());`

Comment: its still giving me the same error

Comment: what IS the error? You've never actually said what error you get, just that you get "an error" (look in the browser developer tools console for the error)

Comment: also, if you've used the exact code in my comment, clearly that doesn't apply - you need to read the documentation

Comment: I described in question that when I press button that handles post call, i'm redirected to empty page with cannot POST written on top instead of expected behaviour. I'm assuming that the server is not getting the post call.

Comment: that's not an error, that's the result of your code ... *check the developer tools console for the error* - do some debugging

Comment: I've been following developer's tool and currently there are no error showing on the console

Comment: just 404 not found when redirected

Comment: right ... 404 ... so the error isn't even CORS - that would've been useful to know **in the question**

Comment: So any other suggestions? I have no idea what is exactly causing 404

Comment: your browser is trying to open a page that doesn't exist

Comment: hmm okay so you mean that fetch url is wrong and causing 404?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the CORS requirement which you stated you've done,

Your form is pointing to `localhost:8080/login` which is in your React application, not express. change the onSubmit method to the form instead of the button.

```
render() { 
        return ( 
          <div>
            <h1>Welcome to Secret Admirer</h1>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> <hr/>
                <label>Enter Your Credentials to sign up</label>
                <div className ="form-group">
                <p>user id: 
                <input  type="text" value = {this.state.id} onChange={this.handleChange} name="id" placeholder="Enter your ID..."  required />
                </p><br/></div>
                <div className = "form-group">
                <p>Password: 
                <input type="text" value = {this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" required />
                </p><br/></div>
             <button className = "btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Sign up"> Sign Up</button>
            </form>

            </div>

        )
}
```

your `res.redirect()` in the express application should also use a full path. If you're redirecting like this `res.redirect('/signin.html');`, it would redirect to `localhost:5000/signinhtml` instead of your React application.

Answer (score 0):

Update `const API = 'http://localhost:8080/';` to `const API = 'http://localhost:5000/'`